# getter and setter with header file c++

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Getter and Setter method not working in Qt thread.

I set `QString` value from main function and I want to get that value from `QThread`.

**My codes**

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "networkthread.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "msg.h"
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str = argv[1];

    QString strb = argv[2];

    msge myObj;
    myObj.setstra(str);

    myObj.setstrb(strb);

    NetworkThread networkThread;

    networkThread.start();
    int result = a.exec();

    networkThread.requestInterruption();
    networkThread.exit();
    networkThread.wait(2000);

    return 0;
}
```

**msg.h**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
using namespace std;

class msge
{
private:
    QString stra;
    QString strb;

public:
    void setstra(QString s)
    {
        stra = s;
    }

    QString getstra()
    {
        return stra;
    }

    void setstrb(QString s)
    {
        strb = s;
    }

    QString getstrb()
    {
        return strb;
    }
};
```

**networkthread.cpp**

```cpp
#include "networkthread.h"
#include "msg.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

void NetworkThread::run()
{

    while (!isInterruptionRequested())
    {
        msge myObj;
        QString str = myObj.getstra();
        QString strb = myObj.getstrb();
        qDebug() << str + "str first";
        qDebug() << strb + "str second";
        break;
    }

    QCoreApplication::quit();
}
```

**networkthread.h**

```cpp
#ifndef NETWORKTHREAD_H
#define NETWORKTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QString>

class NetworkThread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run();

private:
};

#endif // NETWORKTHREAD_H
```

**output**

```
C:\Users\prade\Documents\untitled2\release>untitled2 hello hai
"str first"
"str second"
```

the getter method not worked.

What I did wrong in this?

How can I solve this?

Comment: you have two objects. On one you call setters on the other you call the getters

Comment: just because the two `msge myObj;` have the same name does not magically make them the same object

Comment: you'd get the same output without `QThread`

Comment: Can you explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

In `NetworkThread` you create a new `msge` object

```
void NetworkThread::run()
{

  while(!isInterruptionRequested()) {

 msge myObj;   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 
 QString str = myObj.getstra();
```

This is a different object than you called the setters (`setstra()`) on in **main.cpp**.

The `msge myObj;` in **main.cpp** is not used or passed to `NetworkThread` in anyway.

You will need to pass your values to the `NetworkThread` object and call the setters on its version of the msge object first.

Comment: can you explain in detail ?

Comment: still i can't find the answer ?

Comment: Yes the myObj object in the NetworkThread never gets the setters called on it. Therefore its values do not change.  You need to call the setters on the object created in the NetworkThread or pass the object from main to the thread.